# Create a flow that will fill the first empty row in the Excel table

Tags: power-automate, powerapps

I have an Excel file that contains a table, and Dataverse table from which data is sent to the Excel table. And there is an application that adds a row of data to the Dataverse table.
I need to create a flow that, when adding a row to the Dataverse table, will add this row to the Excel table.
I was able to create a flow that adds a row to an Excel table, but it adds it at the end of the table, resulting in more empty rows before being written.

Help me create a flow that will fill the first empty row in an Excel table, rather than adding a row at the end.

I also tried the flow option of editing a row in an Excel table, for this I selected the ID column (['Date']) in the value line and set it to null. But the check returned me this option, because ID cannot be empty.